# How to call 'from x import *' where x is a variable in Python

Tags: python, import

I am running several python scripts that are exactly the same except for a prefix on the variables. (Just for clarity, I am working with Tweepy and the Twitter API).

I have named each API credential `xx_apicred.py`, `yy_apicred.py`, etc, and these are saved as a separate file in the folder.

Also, I have tables named `xx_info`, `yy_info`, etc. This part is easy to change through string manipulation.

I would like to change this so that it is one file where I pass the xx string as an argument. This works for everything except the `from xx_cred import*`

When I replace it with a string variable, I get the error that `ImportError: No module named 'var'`

Is there a way I can import through a variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would allow strings as module names:

```
import importlib

cred = importlib.import_module('{}_cred'.format(impl))
```

Where `impl` is the chosen implementation `'xx'` or `'yy'`.

Multiple Python libraries use this trick (tornado, rethinkdb...)

Now use like this:

```
cred.module_var
```

If you really want the effect of `from module import *` use:

```
variables = {name: value for name, value in vars(cred).items()
             if not name.startswith('__')}
globals().update(variables)
```

But `import *` is **not** recommended.

Comment: I've tried this one and it doesn't find the module. I've tried `import cred` after and it doesn't find the `cred` module

Comment: Don't try to import it again. Just use `cred` as the module.

Comment: Awesome! It works. Thanks! Is there a way to do an `from xx import*` or do I have to include `cred.variable` each time?

Comment: @pekasus You can use `getattr`: x = getattr(cred, 'variable'). Then you can use `x` instead of `cred.variable`

Comment: Just use `variable = cred.variable` to shorten the name.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question of how to do `from dynamic_name import *`, it only answers the question of how to do `import dynamic_name` which is something different entirely.

Comment: @wim Expended my answer to address this issue.

Comment: `globals().update(vars(cred))` will override everything, including some special values that should be left alone. For example now `__name__` will become the name of the module (e.g. `xx_cred`) meaning that code such as `if __name__ == "__main__": main()` will fail. But `vars` is clearly better than `inspect`.

Comment: @AlexHall Ok. I added some filtering

Answer (score 2):

First of all, let me note that `from module import *` is generally considered bad practice in actual code. It's really just a trick to make interpreter sessions easier. You should either `from module import a, b` or `import module; module.a()`.

If you REALLY want to dynamically bring all names in the module into the current global namespace, you can do this:

```
import importlib

module = importlib.import_module('module')
globs = globals()
for key, value in vars(module).items():
    if key not in globs:
        globs[key] = value
```

This will work and let you use members of `module` unqualified but tools such as IDEs will not understand this magic and will think that your variables are undefined (not that this will stop the code from running, there'll just be highlighted 'errors'). You would be much better off manually creating the variables you need as aliases of the qualified versions as others have mentioned, e.g. `variable = cred.variable`.

Comment: @Apero I don't follow, how are you suggesting to use `getattr` to solve this problem? You don't mention it in your answer. My answer is the only one actually answering OP's question (although I've warned him that his question is a bad idea). Obtaining a module object is not the same as importing all of its elements as you still have to qualify the names of the values in the module, which OP clearly doesn't feel like doing.

Comment: My answer was just an FYI not an answer. I am not an adept of from module import * and I always do import module and then module.something instead. So if the OP was also doing the same a simple getattr would make his like easy but again he should just do module.something and only load the module dynamically as advised by the selected answer.

Answer (score 0):

**extra FYI only** *not to be chosen as best answer*

This is how rethink DB does internally, based on which loop type the user sets:

```
def set_loop_type(library):
    global connection_type

    # find module file
    moduleName = 'net_%s' % library
    modulePath = None
    driverDir = os.path.realpath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
    if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(driverDir, library + '_net', moduleName + '.py')):
        modulePath = os.path.join(driverDir, library + '_net', moduleName + '.py')
    else:
        raise ValueError('Unknown loop type: %r' % library)

    # load the module
    moduleFile, pathName, desc = imp.find_module(moduleName, [os.path.dirname(modulePath)])
    module = imp.load_module('rethinkdb.' + moduleName, moduleFile, pathName, desc)
```

`imp` is a useful python library you can leverage as well.

Comment: From the doc of  `imp`: *In most cases it is preferred you consider using the `importlib` module's functionality over this module.*

Comment: Tell that to the RethinkDB developers ;-) Maybe this falls under some of the edgy cases where impl is better.

Comment: `importlib`: *New in version 3.1.* and *New in version 2.7*. So this RethinkDB code probably predates these.

Comment: Yeah, they must want to be compatible with the widest range of versions which is understandable for a db driver